# How to get Twitter homepage stream with twitter-lite?

Tags: node.js, twitter

I'm using [twitter-lite](https://github.com/draftbit/twitter-lite)

I'm trying to get my homepage stream (getting all the tweets as people tweet, a stream), but I couldn't.

I don't want to filter out anything, I just want to see the stream.

My code

```
const Twitter = require('twitter-lite')

// removed auth info
const client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: '',
  consumer_secret: '',
  access_token_key: '',
  access_token_secret: ''
})

let stream = client.stream('statuses/home_timeline', {})
  .on('start', response => console.log('start'))
  .on('data', tweet => console.log('data', tweet.text))
  .on('ping', () => console.log('ping'))
  .on('error', error => console.log('error', error))
  .on('end', response => console.log('end'))
```

Error

```
error Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  _headers:
   [Object: null prototype] {
     connection: [ 'close' ],
     'content-length': [ '0' ],
     date: [ 'Sun, 01 Mar 2020 15:10:14 GMT' ],
     server: [ 'tsa_b' ],
     'set-cookie':
      [ 'personalization_id="REMOVEDTHIS=="; Max-Age=63072000; Expires=Tue, 1 Mar 2022 15:10:14 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.twitter.com; Secure; SameSite=None',
        'guest_id=REMOVEDTHIS; Max-Age=63072000; Expires=Tue, 1 Mar 2022 15:10:14 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.twitter.com; Secure; SameSite=None' ],
     'strict-transport-security': [ 'max-age=631138519' ],
     'x-connection-hash': [ 'REMOVEDTHIS' ],
     'x-response-time': [ '6' ],
     'x-tsa-request-body-time': [ '1' ] },
  [Symbol(Body internals)]:
   { body:
      PassThrough {
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        _transformState: [Object] },
     disturbed: false,
     error: null },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]:
   { url: 'https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json',
     status: 404,
     statusText: 'Not Found',
     headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object] },
     counter: 0 } }
end
```

I used to use another package called Twit and it was like below. How can I achieve the equivalent (streaming my homepage stream as users tweet) with this package? I don't want to filter out anything, I just want to see the stream.

```
var Twit = require('twit')

var T = new Twit({
  consumer_key: '',
  consumer_secret: '',
  access_token: '',
  access_token_secret: '',
  timeout_ms: 60 * 1000 // optional HTTP request timeout to apply to all requests.
})

var stream = T.stream('user')
stream.on('tweet', tweet => {
 console.log(tweet.text) // new tweet
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The home_timeline is not a stream, it is a REST endpoint that you need to poll, what you are doing to try to stream from it will not work.

Using twit, you were previously getting the "user stream" - this API was removed some time ago, and it is no longer possible to get the home timeline in realtime.

You can do something like this, but you would need to loop or do it every few minutes (bearing in mind rate limits, and assuming you're still using `twitter-lite`, which I think is a very nice library)

```
async function getHomeTimeline() {
  const result = await client.get("statuses/home_timeline");
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
}

getHomeTimeline();
```